# How to manage parallel and sequential version code with least duplication?

Tags: c++, optimization, cuda

I have written a sequential version of a program, and want to parallel it with thrust-CUDA. Notice that these two versions of code are very similar (like `std::vector, thrust::device_vector, thrust::host_vector`), I wonder how can I manage these codes such that user can choose either version at run time while avoiding duplication?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to use thrust vectors? Why don't you use a C++ allocator with managed memory? Then you only need to declare your std::vector with your allocator as the second template parameter and the cuda driver will copy the data from CPU-->GPU automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could template your code on the type of `vector` you are using and write explicit specialisations to perform operations specific to the type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct other_vector { };

template<typename T> struct SpecificImplementation;

template<> struct SpecificImplementation<other_vector>
{
    void SpecificWork() { std::cout << "other_vector specific work\n"; }
};

template<> struct SpecificImplementation<std::vector<int>>
{
    void SpecificWork() { std::cout << "std::vector<int> specific work\n"; }
};

template<typename T>
struct GeneralImplementation : public SpecificImplementation<T>
{
    void CommonWork() { std::cout << "common work\n"; }
    void Run() { this->SpecificWork(); CommonWork(); }
};

int main()
{
    GeneralImplementation<other_vector> i1;
    i1.Run();

    GeneralImplementation<std::vector<int>> i2;
    i2.Run();

    //GeneralImplementation<int> i3; <-- will not compile without implementation
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/V0o23L)